# Prevent <li> from overflowing parent <ul>

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float, html-lists

We have a `menu` that has the following structure below. The goal is to set to a `max-height` on the `<ul class=float-one>` such that after four `<li>` it is always wrapping to the next column.

**How can we prevent the `<li>` from overflowing the parent `<ul>` tag?**

We tried:

1. removing the `max-height`, but without it we are not able to ensure that only four `<li>` items are listed per row.

Goals:

1. wrap into two columns after four `<li>` elements
2. keep next column within the `<ul>`
3. if text goes beyond, `<ul>`, just wrap it within parent `<ul>` tag.

Current issue:

[image: menu issue]

Desired output:

[image: menu desired output]

```css
.containing-div {

  display: block;
  height: auto;
 float: left;
}
.float-one {
 border: 1px solid black;
 
 column-count: 2;
 color: blue;
 width: 70%;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 padding: 32px;
}
.float-one li {
 padding: 18px;
}
.float-two {
 border: 1px dashed green;
 width: 30%;
 margin: 32px;
 margin-left: 0;
}
.floating-div {
  display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 1200px;
}
.floating-div ul {
  display: inline-block;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="containing-div">
    <div class="floating-div">
        <ul class="float-one">
            <li>List Item One</li>
            <li>List Item Two</li>
            <li>List Item Three</li>
            <li>List Item Four</li>
         <li>Monotonectally syndicate resource</li>
            <li> Distinctively implement inte</li>
            <li>ideas for</li>
            <li>List Item Four</li>
         <li>Monotonectally syndicate resource</li>
            <li> Distinctively implement inte</li>
            <li>Proactively brand out</li>
            <li> Assertively harness multifunctional paradigms</li>
        </ul>
    
     <div class="float-two">
        <ul>
            <li>List Item Five</li>
            <li>List Item Six</li>
            <li>List Item Seven</li>
            <li>List Item Eight</li>
      </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Currently when I run your code snippet the output is your desired output. Can I please know whats wrong here exactly?

Comment: remove `column-count` and `.floating-div ul {`, set a `max-height` on `containing-div` so that 4 `li`s are in a column and put `overflow-x: auto` on `float-one`?

Comment: @EvikGhazarian i had accidently left out `max-height: 200px` on the `.floating-div ul` element. It is adjusted to show the issue now when i run the `code snippet`

Comment: @kukkuz in doing so, i was not able to find the solution. I added a `background-color: red` just to see what the results were, but it only showed the element red up to the `max-height`